# I get into another user session when logging in openam

Tags: openam

we have deployed a OpenAM V10 cluster with two nodes and sometimes and several SPs configured. When a user logs into the system, the systems validates its credentials and starts the user session but sometimes it seems to "cross" the session with one from another user whom is already logged into the system. After that, when the user tries to access any of the registered SPs an error is shown and it's forced to be logged again. So, in fact, it's not really a security problem but it's not cool at all.

We really don't know if the problem is in OpenAM or in the load-balancer.

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAM does not use HTTP session but it's own session id which is cryptograhically secure, so it's very unlikely there is a SSO session ID clash.

It's not clear what "cross the session" really means ... a session in you app? Then it's an application issue, not an OpenAM issue.

It will never be an LB issue.

Comment: Hi, Bernhard, I have my own login.jsp and login_ok.jsp where the users enter their credentials and are validated. What "cross session" means is that sometimes at the login_ok.jsp when a user is logged the application shows the firstname and surname of another user

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your app, not with OpenAM